# print a parameter's value, including its type

Tags: r, printing

I have a variable, lets call it `artichoke`, that can be either a sequence or a vector, for example

```r
artichoke <- seq(-5,5)
```

or

```r
artichoke <- c(-5,5)
```

I want to print the value and type of this variable so that I would get:

> seq(-5,5)

in the first case and

> c(-5,5)

in the second.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you be slightly more specific/give a little bit more context in your question? Once the assignment is made (i.e. once `artichoke <- seq(-5,5)` has been parsed and evaluated), the information about the statement that created it is gone. Sequences are not a different type of object from vectors in R. For example, there is no way to tell apart the results of `seq(-5,5,length.out=2)` and `c(-5,5)`. On the other hand, if you wanted to make an auxiliary rule like "a sequence is any vector where `all(diff(x)==1)` is TRUE, we could help you ...

Comment: this variable is used downstream in the script to run some functions. I want to save the parameters for each script run so I want to be able to print the full function information so I can create a sheet with that info. Is this clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `dput()` in R that turns out to be cleverer than I gave it credit for ...

```r
artichoke <- c(-5,5)
dput(artichoke, file=textConnection("art1","w"))
artichoke <- seq(-5,5)
dput(artichoke, file=textConnection("art2","w"))
```

Results:

```r
art1
## [1] "c(-5, 5)"
art2
## [1] "-5:5"
```

R chooses to use the `:` operator rather than `seq()` . You could use something like

```r
sub("(-?[0-9]+):(-?[0-9]+)","seq(\\1,\\2)",art2)
```

to convert the result from `-5:5` to `seq(-5,5)` if you wanted.

If the sequence is more complex `dput()` is not as clever/doesn't recognize it as a sequence:

```r
artichoke <- seq(-5,10,by=2)
dput(artichoke)
## c(-5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
```

If you wanted to recognize this or other more complex cases you'd probably have to write your own rules ...

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, but a small issue, whenever I run the dput command, `dput(artichoke, file=textConnection("art1","w"))` if you then go and change the original variable to a new value, and rund dput again, you get the error message `Error in textConnection("art1", "w") : 
  cannot change value of locked binding for 'art1'`  what i did is just add a `rm(art1)' at the end of the script to make sure it resets, just wanted to put this here for future reference

Comment: you could probably also solve this by explicitly opening the textConnection and assigning it to a separate variable, then explicitly closing and re-opening it ... (with `open()`/`close()`)

Answer (score 2):

If we want to delay the execution, can be wrapped in `quote`

```
artichoke <-  quote(seq(-5, 5))
```

and then `eval` to return the evaluated output

```
eval(artichoke)
#[1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
artichoke
#seq(-5, 5)
```

---

Another option is to create a function, extract the arguments with `match.call()`, `print` it while `return`ing the evaluated expression, and assign it to an object

```
f1 <- function(expr) {
 print(as.list(match.call()[-1])$expr)
  expr
  }

artichoke <- f1(seq(-5, 5))
#seq(-5, 5)

artichoke <- f1(c(-5, 5))
#c(-5, 5)
```

If we need it quoted, then wrap with `deparse`

```
f1 <- function(expr) {
 print(deparse(as.list(match.call()[-1])$expr))
  expr  

 }

artichoke <- f1(seq(-5, 5))
#[1] "seq(-5, 5)"
```

Comment: this works but is there any other way to do this? I would have to change all mentions of artichocke in the code to eval(artichoke) and that is kind of cumbersome.

Comment: @JoãoDuarte Would the updated solution helps?

Comment: Both work in the sense that they give the correct result. I was just hoping I would not have to change all the artichoke dependencies in the rest of the code, which i will have to do with either of these two solutions.     Never thought I would write the words "artichoke dependencies" I am glad i chose that variable name.